Unexpected Redirection from SST Next.js Stack in AWS Lambda
We're facing an issue with an SST-deployed Next.js application where requests to https:// mysite.com//attacker.com/ are unexpectedly redirecting to attacker.com. The logs in AWS Lambda (server Lambda) confirm that the requests are reaching the server (not just served by CloudFront), as I see START and END request logs, but no other details.
To debug, I placed console.log statements at the beginning of getServerSideProps for both index.tsx and [...catchAll].tsx, but these logs do not appear in CloudWatch, even though the function execution starts and ends normally.
Could anyone suggest why these redirections are happening or why my logs aren’t showing? Any insights or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
